# Reference txt file in solution folder across multiple projects for homework assignment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, console-application

Basics of assignment

1. Use Visual Studio (I'm in 2019, thank you school!)
2. Create console app that displays Magic 8 Ball style responses randomly to any text entered in line.

   - This list is stored as a .txt file somewhere within the solution
3. Create windows form app that allows a user to enter new responses that are saved to the list pulled in the console app above

   - This only accepts one line at a time with a listbox displaying the results and a save button for saving. Form has label ("Enter a magic response!"), text box for input, list box for displaying list from .txt file, and save button to add text box entry to .txt file.

I don't know how to reference across projects, and my developer lingo is still too underdeveloped for me to conduct a worthwhile Google search. I simply don't know how to reference a relative path that keeps things contained. I only know how to reference an absolute path:

```cs
StreamWriter outputfile;
outputfile = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\...some-file-path...\Homework2\responses.txt)
```

Or deeper if it's in the bin\debug folder. Speaking of, I don't care if it's in the debug folder of one project or another, or in the main solution folder.

I just want it to work since it's homework (although an explanation of common industry best practices would not be unappreciated, even though I'm going into IT). How do I reference the solution folder as the start of the path to which I need to find a file? I would ask if that's possible, but I know the reality of programming is that anything is possible if you're just willing to put enough knuckle grease into the project.

Comment: If they are in the same  project, you can access the files by the following path, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"../../assets/test.html"`. The value of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is `...\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\bin\Debug`

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain your problem. You've used a lot of words, but is your question really _"How to open a file using a relative path"_?

Comment: Well certainly, it's easy to reword a question into something simple when you know what words to string together. I appreciate your suggestion for how to ask the question better, though. Now I know what to ask. And thank you Kyle for your suggestion, having this knowledge will certainly be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `..` to go up a directory relative to the current one. So going from `C:\Windows\Temp` using `..\..\ProgramData` would get you to `C:\ProgramData`.

The current dir is referenced with `.\` for going downwards in the tree.
So using the previous example `.\Temp1` would get you to `C:\Windows\Temp\Temp1`